# React Redux sync action returns some Proxy object instead of string

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an input with `currentAnswer`:

```
    <input
      value={props.currentAnswer}
      onChange={(text) => dispatch(onChangeAnswer(text))}
    />
```

Which calls function `onChangeAnswer`:

```
export function onChangeAnswer(text) {
  console.log(text);
  return { type: ON_CHANGE_ANSWER, data: text };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function reduce(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case ON_CHANGE_ANSWER:
    return assign({}, state, {
      currentAnswer: action.data
    });
```

Async actions works good, but when I change text in the input I see next object in console:

```
{type: "ON_CHANGE_ANSWER", data: Proxy}
  data: Proxy {dispatchConfig: null, _targetInst: null, …}
  type: "ON_CHANGE_ANSWER"
```

So, I want `data` will be entered in field text.

Should I dispatch it somehow? I obviously have a lack of understanding how all this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy you are getting is React [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) which makes event behave the same across browsers. You need to access the value from `target` which is original HTML Element:

```
<input
  value={props.currentAnswer}
  onChange={(event) => dispatch(onChangeAnswer(event.target.value))}
/>
```

Btw - [events get nullified for performance reasons](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) - so you can't actually pass event do redux.

Comment: Thanks! I was changing my React Native code, in which I also understand not much for now, that where this come from.

Comment: @zishe sure! Good, that you got it now.

Answer (score 1):

the input's onChange is returning an event. What you want to do is change the line

`onChange={(text) => dispatch(onChangeAnswer(text))}`

to this:

`onChange={(text) => dispatch(onChangeAnswer(text.target.value))}`

to get the value you've entered into the input.

Comment: It should probably be renamed `event`