# Redux returning a proxy object instead of the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, proxy, react-redux

I am trying to access my initial state in redux and I am being returned a proxy object. How can I access what is in my state?

It should be returning some large 2D array for a grid. It works fine with small things like booleans but not with this.

That large array returns perfectly when I directly log it on the console but I get this when I set that array to my initial state and log it from there.

```
Proxy {0: {…}}
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true
```

[image]

This is the `initialState`:

```
const initialState = {
  grid: initialGrid,
  isMousePressed: false,
};
```

The grid shows up in the redux state perfectly fine but I can't log it on the console.
I found out from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944105/react-redux-sync-action-returns-some-proxy-object-instead-of-string) that I need to access the value from `target` so
I tried `console.log(state.grid.target)` and everything else on the list but it still does not work.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: what happens when you try `console.info(state.grid.target)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) and its `createSlice` API.

`createSlice` uses Immer internally, which wraps your data in a Proxy so it can track attempted updates.

You need to use the `current` utility from Immer to unwrap the data if you want to log it, as re-exported by RTK:

`console.log(current(state))`

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current